# How to set alias path via webpack in CRA (create-react-app) and craco?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a problem on set *webpack* alias path using *create-react-app* and [*craco*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco), already googling it but can't solve the problem.

I got an error `Module not found: Can't resolve '@app/App' in 'C:\ReactSandbox\my-project\src` everytime i run application using command `yarn start`

### Steps to reproduce:

1. `create-react-app my-project`
2. `cd my-project`
3. `yarn add @craco/craco`
4. `cat > craco.config.js` *(see configuration below)*
5. replace `react-scripts` to `craco` on 'script' section on package.json *(craco start, craco build, etc)*
6. edit file `src/index.js` *(replace line 4, see code below)*
7. `yarn start`

#### craco.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    resolve: { 
      alias: {
        "@app": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
      }
    }    
  }
};
```

#### src/index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from '@app/App'; //replace './App' into '@app/App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

---

#### Current result

`Module not found: Can't resolve '@app/App' in 'C:\ReactSandbox\my-project\src`

#### Expected

I'm avoiding call relative path hell, instead of import module like `../../../../FilterComment.js`, it would be clean to write `@app/FilterComment.js`

Comment: Removing the "resolve: { }" worked for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

resolve for carco:

u need install craco-alias, then will write in
**craco.config.js**

```
    const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias')

    module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        {
          plugin: CracoAlias,
          options: {
            source: 'tsconfig',
            baseUrl: '.',
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.path.json',
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```

**tsconfig.path.json**

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "@/*": ["src/*"],
          "@svg/*": ["src/assets/svg/*"],
          "@img/*": ["src/assets/images/*"],
          "@icons/*": ["src/assets/icons/*"],
          "@shared/*": ["src/shared/*"],
          "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
          "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
          "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
          "@layout/*": ["src/layout/*"],
          "@services/*": ["src/services/*"]
        }
      }
    }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
      "extends": "./tsconfig.path.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "esnext"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "removeComments": true
      },
      "include": [
        "src",
        "src/configs",
        "react-app-env.d.ts"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: this is correct. upvoted. solved my problem atlast.. thankiiies

Comment: Example of how to use? ```import myhooks from @hooks/hooks.tsx```?

Answer (score 7):

#### First - tell to IDE about aliases in tsconfig.json:

create separate file `tsconfig.paths.json` and add aliases:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "paths": {
         "@utils/*": ["utils/*"]
      }
   }
}
```

Add created `tsconfig.paths.json` to main `tsconfig.json`

```
{
   "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
   ... other staff ...
}
```

#### Second - tell to webpack about aliases:

Add aliases to `config-overrides.js`

```
const {
   override,
   addWebpackAlias
} = require('customize-cra');

const path = require("path");

module.exports = override(
   addWebpackAlias({
      "@utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/utils"),
   }),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

my craco.config.js look likes below, it works:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // ...
    webpack: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, './src')),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No eject is needed with craco. I use the same `craco.config.js` alias setting but without `path.join` and it works fine

Comment: Yeah, no need to wrap results of `path.resolve` in `path.join`

Comment: how would this work for the case if we have node package with scope..

like `@sentry/react` etc...

Comment: @MurtazaHussain As per some nodejs docs somewhere, they suggest using `#` instead of `@` which is what I do... it's a bit weird but it works... and node said to do so. I feel like there was a more explicit suggestion for it but [here it is implicitly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). This avoids the clash with `@`

Answer (score 2):

Just keep your file `craco.config.js` just like this, and you need to add 1 more file with named `jsconfig.json`

it's content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "checkJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

## then you can import from the absolute path like `@app/FilterComment.js`

It also worked for VSCode (editor now understand where `@app` point to).
But if you want VSCode to do the import automatically, then you should add more config for it to force it always do the import from absolute path.

file `.vscode/settings.json`
content:

```
{
  "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"
}
```

Comment: react script does not allow you put "paths" in tsconfig.json, it remove automatically for you

Comment: To prevent the react-script script from removing the `paths` from _tsconfig.json_, create _tsconfig.path.json_ (for example), add the `paths` settings and extend in _tsconfig.json_

Answer (score 1):

Use **[react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias)**:

- Install `craco` and `react-app-alias` and create craco config:

```js
// craco.config.js
const {CracoAliasPlugin} = require('react-app-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Replace `react-scripts` with `craco` in package.json.

Create typescript config and alias in separated config like this:

```json
// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "example/*": ["example/src/*"],
      "@app/*": ["app/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  // ...
}
```

Now you can do import like this:

```js
   import App from '@app/App'
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and your other `react-app-rewire-alias`? Which one will you be supporting?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the OP had a different version of React / Webpack (I'm using today's current versions), but putting the `alias` object directly inside the `webpack` object (without nesting it in the `resolve` object) did the trick for me:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      "@app": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

An example (which I'm using) without using dependency:

```js
//craco.config.js
const path = require('path')

const tsconfig = require('./tsconfig.base.json')

const removeAsterisk = path => path.replace('/*', '')

const aliasProps = Object.entries(tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths).map(([key, value]) => {
  const newKey = removeAsterisk(key)
  let newValue = removeAsterisk(value[0])
  newValue = path.resolve(__dirname, newValue)
  return [newKey, newValue]
})

const alias = Object.fromEntries(aliasProps)

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias,
  },
}
```

```js
//tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"],
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {/*...*/}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [craco-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-alias) plugin for automatic aliases generation for Webpack and Jest.
(I am just an intern but that's how senior developers in my company are using absolute imports in react)

Install

```
yarn add @craco/craco
yarn add craco-alias
```

craco.config.js

```
const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        source: 'tsconfig',
        baseUrl: './src',
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.paths.json', // or wherever you have defined your paths
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

And make sure that you scripts in package.json look like the following

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject",
    ...
  },
```

Then It'll work as specified in tsconfig.json.

FYI I have,
`"react-scripts": "4.0.3"`
`"@craco/craco": "^6.3.0"`
`"craco-alias": "^3.0.1"`