# How to set X-Frame-Options headers in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, x-frame-options

I try to set X-Frame-Options headers using this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/68172973/17720329. in local is work fine, but after deploy the headers is not set. can anyone help me?